# Does Iterator Pattern violate Dependency Inversion Principle?

Tags: design-patterns, iterator, solid-principles

In the iterator pattern, we have Iterator and Iteratee interfaces. Each concrete Interatee will have one concrete iterator (E.g. backpackInventory and backpackInterator). The concrete iterator and iteratee look something like this:

```
class BackoackInventory(Inventory):
  ....
  def create_iterator(self):
    return BackpackIterator(self)
  ....

class BackpackIterator(Iterator):
  def __init__(self, inventory: BackpackInventory):
    self._inventory = inventory
  ....
```

In this piece of code, BackpackInventory and BackpackIterator depend on each other. Does it violate the Dependency Inversion Principle? or maybe some other principles related to dependency?

Answer (score 0):

One important point IMPOV is that SOLID principles are not applied to classes, but they are applied in module level. So dependency injection shall apply for module interactions and not for all class interactions.

So in your specific problem, I think there is no problem with the SOLID principles. because iterator and iteratee forms a single module.

Answer (score 0):

This is the loosely coupled and more flexible version of your OP.

This way, BackpackIterator can iterate any concrete object inherited from Inventory .
The basic concept of DIP is try not to depend on concrete object, rather depend on an abstract one. So BackpackIterator should depend on Inventory rather than BackpackInventory.

```
class InventoryIterator:
    def has_next(self):
        pass

    def next(self):
        pass

class Inventory:
    def create_iterator(self):
        pass

class BackpackInventory(Inventory):
    def create_iterator(self):
        return BackpackIterator(self)

class BackpackIterator(InventoryIterator):
    def __init__(self, inventory: Inventory):
        self._inventory = inventory
```